# Lighttpd user directories with individual user processes

Tags: lighttpd, process

I have enabled user directories (mod_userdir) for my lighttpd server but I don't really know how different user processes can be spawned when php files in these directories are ran.

The user's directory and the files in it are owned by the user I want the process to be spawned, but it still keeps running the php scripts as www-data. Is there something with fast-cgi or php-fpm that needs be done?

Thanks in advance.